# Is this possible to do with a Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three divs inside of a flexbox and I want to get them aligned in a certain way. Here is the way the HTML is set up.

```html
 <div class="holder">
    <div class="section-one"></div>
    <div class="section-two"></div>
    <div class="section-three"></div>
 </div>
```

I need the items to lay out like this:

| first column | second column |
| --- | --- |
| section one | section two |
| section one | section three |

I do not actually want them in a table. I need two columns where each item has a width of 50%, but the second and third section are stacked on top of each other. I know one solution is to have two columns, but for reasons I cannot say I cannot do that. I need to have three items that are all in the same row.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post the relavent code so that we can debug this.

Comment: it is possible using grids instead. refer to this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: flexbox operaties basically in one dimension. grid is better suited or a two dimensional layout like this. Investigate grid-template-areas and if you are still stuck put your code into your question with a description of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution with your markup would be to use CSS-Grid. Simply create a 2 column grid and let the first element span 2 rows with `grid-row: span 2`

```css
.holder {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.section-one {
  grid-row: span 2;
}


/* For demo purpose only */
div > div {
  min-height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.holder {
  gap: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="section-one">1</div>
  <div class="section-two">2</div>
  <div class="section-three">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would agree that CSS-grid is a good choice for this - its not hard to do with flexbox.

Simply create two divs aligned horizontally (flex defaults to `flex-direction:row` - so you don't need to specify this) in order to create left and right columns and put the first section div in the left column - then the other two section divs in the right column and use `flex-direction:column` to get the vertical alignment.

```css
.holder {
   display: flex;
   width: 400px
}

.column {
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-basis: 50%;
 border: solid 1px #a9a9a9;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column
}

 .column-header {
background: #d4d4d4;
border-bottom: solid 1px #a9a9a9;
 padding: 8px 16px;

}

.column div:not(.column-header) {
 padding: 8px 16px;
 height: 100%
}

.section-one {
  background: lime
}

.section-two {
  background: aqua;
}

.section-three {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="column left-column">
    <div class="column-header">First Column</div>
    <div class="section-one">section 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right-column">
    <div class="column-header">Second Column</div>
    <div class="section-two">Section 2</div>
    <div class="section-three">section 3</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: While this is a good solution, it requires sections two and three to be in a different column than section one which I cannot have. thank you for the input though! If I could go with the two-column layout I definitely would have!